# Crashes when calling delegate method inside URLSession closure

Tags: swift, crash, urlsession

I created class named `FileTransferManager` which manages upload/download task using URLSession.

Because of code's length, I created a gist of my code. : https://gist.github.com/Cyanide7523/eb2f7a743459055e13b8568a51f644f3

And I created delegate protocol to recognize the transfer result.

This is a sample usage of this class :

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController, FileTransferDelegate{

    let fileMan = FileTransferManager()

    fileMan.delegate = self

    fileMan.download( /* Some parameters */ )

    func fileTransferManager(_ sender: FileTransferManager, didSucceedDownload data: Data, ...) {

        print("Download Succeed!")
    }
}
```

But when `FileTransferManager` calls delegate functions, App always crashes with message "unrecognized selector sent to instance" and I can't figure out why does this crashes.

+++ Error logs

```
2018-06-27 14:31:57.851160+0900 Project[1428:2194695] -[Project.InitialViewController fileTransferManagerWithSender:willDownload:at:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10207a0e0
2018-06-27 14:31:57.851783+0900 Project[1428:2194695] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Project.InitialViewController fileTransferManagerWithSender:willDownload:at:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10207a0e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184d1ad8c 0x183ed45ec 0x184d28098 0x18ee0adb0 0x184d202d4 0x184c0641c 0x1003974b0 0x100399094 0x100396d8c 0x1852a9e4c 0x1852c2b6c 0x185742e88 0x1856848d0 0x185683cac 0x101ec119c 0x101ecd7cc 0x101ec119c 0x101ecd7cc 0x101ecd6b0 0x185744750 0x101ec119c 0x101ece454 0x101eccd44 0x101ed27c8 0x101ed2500 0x18493ffac 0x18493fb08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Why do you forcibly unwrap method self.delegate?.fileTransferManager!   ?

Comment: 'cause Xcode tells me the error : `Value of optional type '((FileTransferManager, String, String, String?, Error) -> ())?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` so I put it. Can it makes problem?

Comment: Ok. Xcode tells you that because methods in protocol are "optional". The URSession might call some methods other than "didSucceedDownload" that you implemented. In case of force-unwrapping "optional" method it should be implemented in class that conforms to protocol.

Comment: Then editing method `self.delegate?.fileTransferManager!` to `self.delegate?.fileTransferManager?` would solve the problem? It seems like Xcode doesn't tell any errors with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you implement `@objc optional func fileTransferManager(_ sender: FileTransferManager, willDownload contentID: String, at room: String)` method in `InitialViewController`? Also, make your FileTransferManager delegate reference "weak" and remove all force-unwrap's when you call delegate methods (just replace "!" by "?").